# Why did Tufte call this a "superbly produced duck"?

Tags: visualization, terminology

I think I understand Tufte's concept of a "[Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Duck)" -- A graphic that is taken over by decorative forms.

But I couldn't understand why he called this a duck (a "superbly produced" one at that). It seemed to me more functional than decorative.

Thoughts?

[image: Tufte - "superbly produced duck"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you assume **duck** to mean "irrelevant decorative elements" there are a few things that strike me as likely: (1) the "squares" only roughly indicate location of the target area; (2) squares represent volume, which is incongruent when overlaid on 2d geography; (3) shading of mountains/geographic features doesn't add detail.

Also problematic: comparison of h20 volume applied to crop types is difficult to discern using grids. Quick, which crop color uses more water??

[image]

If you want to *compare volume to crop type* then you should use a plain column chart, where it is easy to distinguish relative heights. This is analogous to why bar/column charts are preferable to pie charts - humans are better at comparing heights/lengths vs area/volume. If, on the other hand, the point of the graph is to *compare crop type irrigation by area*, you would want to display a column graph with regions next to each other, but grouped by crop type.

As far as a **superbly produced** duck, my guess is that the Applied Irrigation Water  is a duck, but a superb duck, at least when compared to the monstrous duck on the preceding page of the Visual Display of Quantitative Information 2nd Ed.

[image: horrible duck]

Answer (score 1):

In The Visual Display of Quantitative Information, page 116-7, Tufte explains [both the concept of a 'duck' and its provenance](https://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=00040Z). There is a small service building in Flanders NY called 'The Big Duck' whose form is the shape of ... a duck. It is a form without function, that is its own end and shows, in data graphics, hardly any data at all.

[image: Th Big Duck in Flanders NY]